# KVO not working with UISwitch

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, uiswitch

For the life of me I can't get KVO working with UISwitch. I have a custom UITableViewCell with  a UISwitch added through Interface Builder. I created an IBOutlet for the UISwitch and linked it to `theSwitch` variable.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
           [theSwitch addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"on" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"toggled switch");
}
```

observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context is never called!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it's possible that UISwitch simply isn't KVO-compliant.

No matter, because you can just use control events:

```
[theSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// ...
- (void)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender {
    if (sender.on) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now and it works but I use KVO everywhere else so I want to keep my code consistent. Things like this should just work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

theSwitch might not have been initialized when you add the observer. try adding the observer in awakeFromNib.

Comment: Actually, not all Apple's classes are KVO compliant. That was the problem here.